# c++ virtual Diamond inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

Lets say we got a diamond inheritance where D inherit from both B1 and B2 whose base are V as follows:

```
struct V { 
    V(){cout << "V()" << endl;}
    V(int){cout << "V(int)" << endl;}
}; 
struct B1 : virtual V {
    B1(){cout << "B1()" << endl;}
    B1(int i): V(i) {cout << "B1(int)" << endl;
        /*…*/ }
};
struct B2 : virtual V {
    B2(){cout << "B2()" << endl;}
    B2(int i) { cout << "B2()" << endl; }
};
struct D : B1, B2 {
    D(int i): V(i) { cout << "D(int)" << endl; }
};
```

when I initialize D* parameter, I expect that B1 and B2 default Constructors to call V constructor. However when I ran the next line, V was called once. Why?

```
D* d = new D(1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short: virtual base classes are initialised by the constructor of the most derived class.

Comment: This is exactly what virtual inheritance is for.  If you do want two different `V` subobjects, don't use virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for a virtual base is always called just once, from the most derived class; that's just how it works. It wouldn't make sense to construct the base more than once.

Try adding a parameter to the base constructor and see what happens.

Comment: is that right to say that in inheritance, the derived class is responsible for constructing all the base classes?

Comment: @HeshamYassin No.  The most derived class is responsible for constructing all virtual base classes and its immediate bases.

Answer (score 0):

The base class `V` is called once because `V1` and `V2` inhert virtualy from V. If you hasn't the possibility to inhert virtualy a problem will occure: for example if I call a method of base class from a derived the compiler cannot know which base class call, that one constructed from `V1` or the other constructed from `V2`.

So virtual inheritance give us the possiblity to have the diamond inehritance without this issue.